# Configuring a UITableViewCell object with unique image and text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Given a `.plist` similar to :

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Afghanistan</string>
        <key>government</key>
        <string>Islamic Republic</string>
        <key>population</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>/Flags/afghanistan.png</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Albania</string>
        <key>government</key>
        <string>Emerging Democracy</string>
        <key>population</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>/Flags/albania.png</string>
    </dict>
.... etc.
```

And **ViewController.m** :

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize sortedCountries;

-(void)viewDidLoad  {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"plist"];  

    NSArray *countries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease];
    self.sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];


}   

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *country = [sortedCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *countryName = [country objectForKey:@"name"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[sortedCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey:@"image"] ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    cell.imageView.image = theImage;
    cell.textLabel.text = countryName;
    return cell; 

    }
```

This puts `countryName` in ascending alphabetical order as expeted in the UITableView Cells. What is not working is `cell.imageView.image`.

It puts afghanistan.png in the first UITableViewCell as expected. The Cells that follow also receive afghanistan.png as well however. ( The second cell should receive 'albania.png', etc ). How can I fix this UIImageView problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imageNamed` instead.

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];
```

Comment: Where you have `UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];` change it to `UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];`

Comment: @WrightCS Thanks, but when I make that change theImage returns (null)?

Comment: Well, in your example, use: `[UIImage imageNamed:path];`, because "path" should be returning "image.png".

Comment: Maybe I messed something up or am confused, but I am trying to get the imageView to return 'afghanistan.png' for the first cell, 'albania.png' for the second cell..etc I shouldn't be returning 'image.png'..?

Comment: then you need to use `[item objectForKey:@"imageKey"]`. Use NSLog to figure out what is being returned.

Comment: Still get afghanistan.png in every cell... Is there something wrong with my .plist? I have the 'image' key set to the file path to the image (  /Flags/<name of country> ).. It just seems to grab the first .png in the path and does not go beyond. Or maybe there is a problem with the location of the .png's?

Comment: Thanks . I figured it out with your help. I captured the path to an  NSString. And then did a UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:pathToFlag];

Answer (score 1):

You should use
`[item objectForKey:@"image"]` in stead of 
`[item objectForKey:@"imageKey"]` 
(as the .plist uses `<key>image</key>`).

Comment: thanks - that was a typo in the post. I had 'image' in the actual project code, but still have same problem..Will update post

Comment: OK, like described by WrightsCS: instead of 
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey:@"image"] ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;

just use
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[item objectForKey:@"image"]];

Comment: +1 I did it a slightly different way. See comment above. But thanks